# Cannot visit to the path i specified in rspec visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have used rspec visit to go to a path but it takes me to the index. I have checked callbacks but still cannot find a clue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
describe "addon purchased" do
    it "should send email when addons are purchased" do
      skip_alpine
      sign_in(@attendee)
      visit manage_tickets_v2_kwivrr_event_path(@event)
      close_cookies_notification
      skip_login_interrupts(@attendee)
      expect(page).to have_content(@event.name)
```

visit not taking me to this specified path

here is my controller action

```
def manage_tickets
    authorize @event
@addon_success_msg = params[:addon_msg] if params[:addon_msg].present?
    
  end
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you tried, that will help to understand the issue?

Comment: Please elaborate on what the controller and the test looks like. What ist the error message, and what is written into the log file when running the failing spec?

Comment: @spickermann errror was: css not found. It is obvious as i had expected something that is not in the index page but on the specified path page